# JavaFX error al llenar TableView con datos de una Base de Datos

Tags: java, javafx

A ver si alguien me puede ayudar...

Estoy intentando leer los datos de una base de datos, y mostrarlos en una TableView. El problema es que en una columna en concreto no muestra los datos:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Y me da el siguiente error:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Según he estado buscando por diferentes sitios, cuando a la gente le daba el mismo problema era o bien porque no tenía las propias variables creadas en la clase Persona, o porque no tenía los Getter y los Setters y por lo tanto no podía acceder a los datos.
En mi caso tengo tanto las correspondientes variables en la clase Persona, como sus Getters y Setters.

Por lo que no soy capaz de encontrar el problema...

Os dejo la clase Persona y el Controlador para que le echéis un vistazo a ver si alguien sabe donde la estoy liando...

Clase Persona:

```
String nombre;
String numPersonal;
String categoria;
String fechaAlta;
String fechaBaja;

Connection conexion;

public Persona(){
}

public Persona(String nombre, String numPersonal, String categoria, String fechaAlta, String fechaBaja) {
    this.nombre = nombre;
    this.numPersonal = numPersonal;
    this.categoria = categoria;
    this.fechaAlta = fechaAlta;
    this.fechaBaja = fechaBaja;
}


public String getNombre() {

    return nombre;
}

public void setNombre(String nombre) {

    this.nombre = nombre;
}

public String getNumPersonal() {
    return numPersonal;
}

public void setNumPersonal(String numPersonal) {
    this.numPersonal = numPersonal;
}

public String getCategoria() {

    return categoria;
}

public void setCategoria(String categoria) {

    this.categoria = categoria;
}

public String getFechaAlta() {

    return fechaAlta;
}

public void setFechaAlta(String fechaAlta) {

    this.fechaAlta = fechaAlta;
}

public String getFechaBaja() {

    return fechaBaja;
}

public void setFechaBaja(String fechaBaja) {

    this.fechaBaja = fechaBaja;
}



public ObservableList<Persona> getPersonas() {

    ObservableList <Persona> personaList = FXCollections.observableArrayList();

    try{
        Class.forName("com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver");

        conexion = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost/ejercicio1interfaces","root","");

        String SQL="SELECT * FROM persona";

        Statement stmt = conexion.createStatement();
        ResultSet resul = stmt.executeQuery(SQL);

        while(resul.next()){

            String no=resul.getString("nombre");
            String nu=resul.getString("numeroPersonal");
            String cat=resul.getString("categoria");
            String alt=resul.getString("fechaAlta");
            String baj=resul.getString("fechaBaja");

            Persona pers = new Persona(no,nu,cat,alt,baj);

            personaList.add(pers);

        }


        stmt.close();
        resul.close();

    } catch (SQLException | ClassNotFoundException e){
        Alert alerta = new Alert(Alert.AlertType.CONFIRMATION);
        alerta.setTitle("AVISO");
        alerta.setContentText(e+"");
        alerta.showAndWait();
    }
    return personaList;
}
```

La clase del controlador:

public class ControladorMantenimiento implements Initializable {

```
@FXML
private Button btnModificar;
@FXML
private Button btnEliminar;
@FXML
private Button btnUsuarios;
@FXML
private TextField txtBuscar;

private static Connection conexion = null;

@FXML
private TableView<Persona> tabla;
@FXML
private TableColumn <Persona,String> columNombre;
@FXML
private TableColumn <Persona,String> columNumero;
@FXML
private TableColumn <Persona,String> columCategoria;
@FXML
private TableColumn <Persona,String> columAlta;
@FXML
private TableColumn <Persona, String> columBaja;
@FXML
ObservableList <Persona> items;





@Override
public void initialize(URL url, ResourceBundle resourceBundle) {

    this.columNombre.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory("nombre"));
    this.columNumero.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory("numeroPersonal"));
    this.columCategoria.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory("categoria"));
    this.columAlta.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory("fechaAlta"));
    this.columBaja.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory("fechaBaja"));

    Persona pers = new Persona();

    items= pers.getPersonas();


    this.tabla.setItems(items);

}
```

Comment: He tardado 30 segundos en ver que tu clase tiene la propiedad `numPersonal` y en la celda de tu tabla le indicas `numeroPersonal`. Revisar dos veces lo que se ha escrito es importante... llamarle a las cosas siempre con el mismo nombre, también. Java no hace magia, si dos cosas no se llaman igual, no son la misma cosa. Te recomiendo aprender inglés, porque yo tardé 20 segundos en verlo porque el error que te da indica exactamente este error que he citado... es literalmente la descripción de tu error. Si quieres programar, aprende inglés. Te hará falta

Comment: Efectivamente... El caso es que lo tenía bien puesto y lo cambié porque estuve probando cosas para solucionar otro fallo que me dio antes y ya pues lo dejé así y ni me di cuenta...  muchas gracias!